# How do you convert a character to a real in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

If I'm trying to do this:

Convert #”N” to a real

What ML expression would do this?

In the same way that:\

```
str = Char -> string
chr = int -> Char
ord = Char -> int
real = int -> real
```

Is there an ML expression like the ones stated above that can convert char -> real?

The input would be something like:

```
real #"N";
```

and the output would be:

```
val it = "whatever the value is": real
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output? (I ask because, although I can think of some conversions from char to real, I can't think of any circumstances where any of them would make sense, so I can't guess which one you want. For that matter, you might also want to explain *why* you want this conversion, in case there's actually a better way to achieve your real goal.)

Comment: @ruakh I have edited the question a bit to explain what exactly I meant by converting the 2. I was wondering if there were any built-in functions that could convert them

Comment: What would the result of this conversion be? (Your example doesn't say anything.) Note that your "in the same way" examples don't do similar things – the first converts from a character to a single-character string; the second and third to and from the encoding of a character; and the fourth from an integer value to the same floating-point value.

Comment: If you just want an expression of the correct type, `real o ord` will do it. Whether that is what you intend to do is difficult to guess. (I suspect that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and that your actual problem can be solved in a better way.)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is in the documentation for the [`CHAR` signature](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/char.html).

Comment: See the documentation for the `REAL` signature on the same page for functions for converting back and forth from int to real and vice versa.

Comment: Just a heads up, I realized afterward the answer I was looking for is closer to what @molbdnilo mentioned: real(ord(#"N"); Sorry for any miscommunication of the answer I was looking for on my part

Answer (score 1):

**No you would need to use two functions:**

real(ord(#"N"));

**Breakdown:**

ord(#"N"); ...... converts to ascii value, 78.

real(78); .......... converts int to real, 78.0.